# What is the use of Autowiring?

Tags: spring

I have two classes Employee and Address. My Employee class needs Address class as a dependency. So i will be doing @AutoWired Address address.  Instead of wriring @Autowired I could have write

`Address address = new Address();`

Why we are writing Autowired. What more advantage it gives on top of other 
way of writing.

```
class Employee{
    @Autowired
    Address address;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Autowired` ensures that `spring context (Application context)` produces object for the said reference you declared autowired on  during your run time implicitly.Its something called dependency injection .You give control to spring to manage your objects ,so you don't have to create objects manually.Just like you said using `new Class()`

Spring identifies classes for  whom the dependencies is made who have annotation under `@Component` Category Like (`@Controller,@Service`),and when you autowire using constructor ,setter etc (using `@Autowired`),spring `Application Context` gives you the object (giving memory automatically) at runtime.

> It makes spring responsible for all object management (memory
>   management,creating and destroying object),which makes your
>   application less prone to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Employee is probably an entity class (a class whose data is populated from some kind of persistent data). You don't `@Autowire` entities, there are other ways to represent table joins like `@OneToMany`.

Let's say you have a DAO class responsible for retrieving `Employee` entities from wherever they are persisted. And you also have a service class responsible for processing those entities. To handle this in the `Spring` way, you'd add an `@Repository` annotation to the DAO class, and an `@Service` annotation to the service class, which tells `Spring` to manage them. Now the service needs a reference to the repository class before it can do its thing, so you `@Autowire` the repository into the service and `Spring` automagically provides the repository reference for you.